# Not able to create table on Oracle db using ojdbc through Java

Tags: oracle, netbeans

I am trying to create a table on an Oracle database through following Java code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.*;

public class TestJDBC
{

public TestJDBC()
{
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    //String s = "Create table phone(fullname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,phnumber VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)";
    //String s1 = "INSERT INTO phone VALUES ('Ted Nicholson', '201 555-1212')";
    //String s2 = "SELECT * FROM phone";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundexception)
    {
        System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.err.println(classnotfoundexception.getMessage());
    }
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Trying to connect...");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@prophet.njit.edu:1521:course", "k45", "XXXX");
        System.out.println("connected!");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("Create table addressbook(first VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, last VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(15), email VARCHAR(30), dob  date, Sex char(10)");
        //statement.executeUpdate(s);
        System.out.println("Created Table.");
        //statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO phone VALUES('Ted Nicholson', '201 555-1212'");
        //System.out.println("Inserted one record.");
        //String s3;
        //for(ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(s2); resultset.next(); System.out.println(s3))
            //s3 = (new StringBuilder()).append(resultset.getString(1)).append(" ").append(resultset.getString(2)).toString();

        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlexception)
    {
        System.err.print("SQLException: ");
        System.err.println(sqlexception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

I get following error:

> Trying to connect...
>   connected!
>   SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: try to run that create table query manually via SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
Create table addressbook(first VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, last VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, phone VARCHAR(15), email VARCHAR(30), dob  date, Sex char(10)
```

needs a ")".